# Duas foreign key na mesma coluna EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent-api

Estou com uma dúvida, estou programando com .NET MVC utilizando o Entity Framework. No momento possuo:

```
class Produto
{
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual UsuarioSistema CadastradoPor { get; set; }
    public virtual UsuarioVisitante CadastradoPor { get; set; }

}
```

O problema é: o campo 'CadastradoPor' deve ter o FK da Entidade UsuarioSistema OU UsuarioVisitante.

*A Entidade UsuarioSistema possui muitos atributos a mais que a Entidade UsuarioVisitante, por isso estão separadas.*

Mas mesmo a UsuarioVisitante sendo simples e limitada, ela também pode cadastrar um produto. Como devo fazer o relacionamento na entidade Produto?

```
class UsuarioVisitante : Usuario
{
    public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Você tem uma tabela para UsuarioSistema e outra para UsuarioVisitante?

Comment: Isso, uma tabela UsuarioSistema, UsuarioVisitante e Produto. Não montei juntas pois UsuarioSistema possui muitos outros atributos que não são necessários para UsuarioVisitante.

Comment: Eu me refiro ao banco de dados mesmo... E na tabela Produto, você tem uma coluna "CadastradoPor" para usuário do sistema e outra para usuário visitante?

Comment: Não, ai que está a questão. Eu não queria fazer duas colunas, pois o produto será cadastrado por um UsuarioSistema ou UsuarioVisitante. Entende? A coluna CadastradoPor deveria receber um foreign key de UsuarioSistema ou UsuarioVisitante.

Comment: E como vc vai saber quando um CadastradoPor é de um ou de outro

Answer (score 0):

Então, você está confundindo algumas coisas. EF com Entidade, Tabela com Classe e Atributo com Coluna.

**Primeiro:**

```
public virtual UsuarioSistema CadastradoPor { get; set; }
public virtual UsuarioVisitante CadastradoPor { get; set; }
```

Você não pode ter dois **Atributos** com o mesmo nome na mesma **Classe**, assim como não consegue declarar a mesma variável duas vezes no mesmo escopo.

**Segundo:**

No banco de dados você não poderá ter uma única coluna, `[CriadoPor]` com FK para as duas `UsuarioSistema` e `UsuarioVisitante`. Suspeito que a `FK` seja para a Tabela `[Usuario]` que deve ter uma Coluna `[Tipo]` que você usa para diferenciar se ele é "Sistema" ou "Visitante"